# Line-Breaks and Typography in CSS

Tags: css, text, line-breaks, typography

I would like to know if it is possible to have line-breaking text that sometimes consists of one line and sometimes of two. I can best describe what i mean it with an image:

[image: breaking text image]

Comment: Define “line-breaking text” and specify how the text is structured. How is the smaller text supposed to appear in HTML source and how is it to be laid out. Showing a *real* example might help in understanding what you want.

Comment: I was basically looking for a liquid (universal?) way to do it. and I don't have a real starting point. I would like to define which text-portions are to be set double-lines ("smaller text") and which should be singled.

Comment: Do you mean that some fragment of text would be laid as two lines, of equal length as far as possible, and a box containing these lines would appear between normally laid fragments of texts and would line-wrap if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to insert the text into separate elements which have the shape and size you want to achieve the effect you are going for. It is not possible with just one html tag.

Comment: Thank you watson. Does this mean I couldn't really make it "liquid" / I would need a fixed, static layout of text? I'm sorry - this is all a little new to me.

Comment: @bennniii Yes. You could try to automatically lay out the text in different elements using some JavaScript, but I don't think that's worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

As Watson said, you'll have to contain the elements in containers of a specific shape and size. You can't make them truly "fluid" as I think you're meaning to comment, however, you can use percentages for those containers to determine how much text is visible in space and possibly viewport sized text to try and properly fill those spaces. Definitely no manner in my mind that will allow you to easily create this in a universal method for all browsers. You're going to have a lot of ragged edges I'd suspect.